# setState( ) in react

Tags: reactjs

here I receive data from server and I want to setState blocks as data received.
but it gives an error:
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {timeStamp, hash, lastHash, data, difficulty, nonce}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

this is the code:
the problem is from setState.

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
        import axios from "axios";
        class Blocks extends Component {
          state = {
            blocks: []
          };
          async componentDidMount() {
            const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/blocks");
            console.log(response.data);
            this.setState({ blocks:response.data});
          }
          render() {
            return (
              <>
              
                <div className="container bg-warning rounded-2 pb-2">
                  <h2 className="m-3">Blocks</h2>
                  {this.state.blocks.map((block) => {
                    return (
                      <div className="container-fluid mb-3">
                        <div className="bg-light p-2 rounded-top">
                          <h3>Timestamp: {block.timeStamp},</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div className="bg-info p-2 ">
                          <h3>hash: {block.hash},</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div className="bg-info p-2 ">
                          <h3>Lasthash: {block.lastHash},</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div className="bg-info p-2 ">
                          <h3>
                            Data: {block.data.length === 0 ? "{Empty}" : block.data},
                          </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div className="bg-info p-2 ">
                          <h3>difficulty: {block.difficulty},</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div className="bg-info p-2 rounded-bottom">
                          <h3>nonce: {block.nonce},</h3>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    );
                  })}
                </div>
              </>
            );
          }
        }
        
        export default Blocks;
```

Comment: What is the output of  `console.log(response.data);`

Comment: `block.data` is probably an Array since you check its' length and it can not be be rendered this way. Be more careful with your data.

Comment: an array with 11 object inside. each object has this format:{data:....,lastHash:......,....}

Comment: I use JSON.stringify(block.data) and it works!

Comment: You can not render object `block.data` like this, you must have render function or a component that renders it.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Blocks extends React.Component {
    state = {
        blocks: []
    }
    
    fetchBlocks = () => {
        fetch('https://some-api.com/harry-potter')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(block=> {
            this.setState({ blocks: blockLists});
        });
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
        <>
            <button onClick={this.fetchBlocks}>Load Blocks</button>
            {this.blocks.length > 0 && (
                <ul>
                    {this.state.blocks.map((blocks) => (
                        <li key={blocks.id}>{blocks.name}</li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            )}
            
        </>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: what if `blockLists` is an Object instead after the data from server ...

Comment: Please explain your answer